# Popover ou Tooltip Bootstrap com texto longo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Como exibir um texto longo e com as quebras em um Popover ou Tooltip do Bootstrap Twitter?
E tem mais um problema, o popover só abre no segundo clique! Alguém sabe o porque disso?

O que fiz:

```
$('.btn-text-pop').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).popover({html:true});
});

$('.btn-text-too').tooltip();
```

e o html

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-text-pop"
    data-original-title="" 
    data-container="body"
    title=""
    data-content="Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami tri-tip capicola landjaeger. Kielbasa flank turkey ham hock, fatback capicola chuck jerky tail. Drumstick venison bresaola, ham hock brisket flank doner shankle tail spare ribs short ribs bacon turducken. Pancetta kielbasa turkey pork loin, turducken jerky strip steak. Pancetta shank t-bone tail, beef sirloin jowl frankfurter chicken jerky leberkas beef ribs swine hamburger turkey. Turducken ribeye jerky ball tip shank, capicola corned beef meatloaf frankfurter. Pork belly drumstick prosciutto jerky chicken tail pork loin, shoulder landjaeger sirloin sausage pig.

Chuck pork belly ribeye beef ribs. Kielbasa swine beef pancetta, boudin chicken doner beef ribs shankle venison landjaeger corned beef jowl capicola. Pastrami kielbasa flank, pig brisket turducken cow beef ribs porchetta landjaeger turkey. Pork shankle kielbasa corned beef hamburger filet mignon turducken. Strip steak ham hock t-bone tongue prosciutto drumstick. Sirloin jerky rump meatball. Shoulder capicola jerky meatball, sirloin short loin ground round drumstick rump filet mignon shankle.

Tail pork t-bone beef ribs. Kielbasa ham hock pig venison, salami porchetta capicola ball tip shoulder biltong pork chop filet mignon beef ribs. Spare ribs kevin leberkas capicola, shankle pork belly ham strip steak swine. Salami capicola tongue spare ribs, ham venison meatball.

Tri-tip ribeye biltong beef ribs shankle chicken turducken jerky. Pork loin landjaeger capicola salami, rump kielbasa pork chop shank spare ribs kevin jowl. Chicken drumstick bacon leberkas, jowl tri-tip ground round venison andouille short ribs pork loin boudin flank shankle. Short loin shank ribeye swine, bresaola shankle jerky drumstick. Meatloaf shoulder turkey prosciutto corned beef, boudin meatball shankle venison doner pork chop rump biltong pig shank.

T-bone landjaeger porchetta pancetta. Ham hock tail sausage meatball pig fatback. Jowl frankfurter landjaeger biltong capicola sausage tri-tip salami sirloin jerky kevin doner. Tri-tip sausage chicken boudin ham.

Does your lorem ipsum text long for something a little meatier? Give our generator a try… it’s tasty!">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
</button>

<br><br>

<button 
    type="button" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-placement="right"
    class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-text-too"
    title="Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami tri-tip capicola landjaeger. Kielbasa flank turkey ham hock, fatback capicola chuck jerky tail. Drumstick venison bresaola, ham hock brisket flank doner shankle tail spare ribs short ribs bacon turducken. Pancetta kielbasa turkey pork loin, turducken jerky strip steak. Pancetta shank t-bone tail, beef sirloin jowl frankfurter chicken jerky leberkas beef ribs swine hamburger turkey. Turducken ribeye jerky ball tip shank, capicola corned beef meatloaf frankfurter. Pork belly drumstick prosciutto jerky chicken tail pork loin, shoulder landjaeger sirloin sausage pig.

Chuck pork belly ribeye beef ribs. Kielbasa swine beef pancetta, boudin chicken doner beef ribs shankle venison landjaeger corned beef jowl capicola. Pastrami kielbasa flank, pig brisket turducken cow beef ribs porchetta landjaeger turkey. Pork shankle kielbasa corned beef hamburger filet mignon turducken. Strip steak ham hock t-bone tongue prosciutto drumstick. Sirloin jerky rump meatball. Shoulder capicola jerky meatball, sirloin short loin ground round drumstick rump filet mignon shankle.

Tail pork t-bone beef ribs. Kielbasa ham hock pig venison, salami porchetta capicola ball tip shoulder biltong pork chop filet mignon beef ribs. Spare ribs kevin leberkas capicola, shankle pork belly ham strip steak swine. Salami capicola tongue spare ribs, ham venison meatball.

Tri-tip ribeye biltong beef ribs shankle chicken turducken jerky. Pork loin landjaeger capicola salami, rump kielbasa pork chop shank spare ribs kevin jowl. Chicken drumstick bacon leberkas, jowl tri-tip ground round venison andouille short ribs pork loin boudin flank shankle. Short loin shank ribeye swine, bresaola shankle jerky drumstick. Meatloaf shoulder turkey prosciutto corned beef, boudin meatball shankle venison doner pork chop rump biltong pig shank.

T-bone landjaeger porchetta pancetta. Ham hock tail sausage meatball pig fatback. Jowl frankfurter landjaeger biltong capicola sausage tri-tip salami sirloin jerky kevin doner. Tri-tip sausage chicken boudin ham.

Does your lorem ipsum text long for something a little meatier? Give our generator a try… it’s tasty!">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
</button>
```

Segue link para o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr2pz6sk/)

Comment: Vê o meu update e vê se é assim que queres: http://jsfiddle.net/kr2pz6sk/2/ Quanto ao click aqui funciona ao primeiro click.

Comment: @JorgeB. Aqui só abre no segundo clic, tanto o do AP como o teu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coloque diferente:

```
$(function(){   
    $('.btn-text-pop').popover({html:true});        
    $('.btn-text-too').tooltip();
});
```

Porque, primeiro ele está executando um evento `click` para adicionar `popover` no referente botão, por isso que ele só vai funcionar na segunda vez, então, coloque na hora do término do carregamento DOM da forma acima.

***Exemplo Online:*** [**JSFildde**](http://jsfiddle.net/8peosk5f/)

Com quebra de linhas (`<br>`) nos `tooltip` e `popover` coloque como configuração `{html:true}` no Javascript ou um na **tag** `button` `data-html="true"` e adicione `<br>` a vontade...

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="popover" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-text-pop"
    data-original-title="" data-container="body" title="" data-html="true"
    data-content="Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami tri-tip capicola landjaeger. Kielbasa flank turkey ham hock, fatback capicola chuck jerky tail. Drumstick venison bresaola, ham hock brisket flank doner shankle tail spare ribs short ribs bacon turducken. Pancetta kielbasa turkey pork loin, turducken jerky strip steak. Pancetta shank t-bone tail, beef sirloin jowl frankfurter chicken jerky leberkas beef ribs swine hamburger turkey. Turducken ribeye jerky ball tip shank, capicola corned beef meatloaf frankfurter. Pork belly drumstick prosciutto jerky chicken tail pork loin, shoulder landjaeger sirloin sausage pig.<br><br>
Chuck pork belly ribeye beef ribs. Kielbasa swine beef pancetta, boudin chicken doner beef ribs shankle venison landjaeger corned beef jowl capicola. Pastrami kielbasa flank, pig brisket turducken cow beef ribs porchetta landjaeger turkey. Pork shankle kielbasa corned beef hamburger filet mignon turducken. Strip steak ham hock t-bone tongue prosciutto drumstick. Sirloin jerky rump meatball. Shoulder capicola jerky meatball, sirloin short loin ground round drumstick rump filet mignon shankle.
<br><br>
Tail pork t-bone beef ribs. Kielbasa ham hock pig venison, salami porchetta capicola ball tip shoulder biltong pork chop filet mignon beef ribs. Spare ribs kevin leberkas capicola, shankle pork belly ham strip steak swine. Salami capicola tongue spare ribs, ham venison meatball.
<br>
Tri-tip ribeye biltong beef ribs shankle chicken turducken jerky. Pork loin landjaeger capicola salami, rump kielbasa pork chop shank spare ribs kevin jowl. Chicken drumstick bacon leberkas, jowl tri-tip ground round venison andouille short ribs pork loin boudin flank shankle. Short loin shank ribeye swine, bresaola shankle jerky drumstick. Meatloaf shoulder turkey prosciutto corned beef, boudin meatball shankle venison doner pork chop rump biltong pig shank.
<br><br>
T-bone landjaeger porchetta pancetta. Ham hock tail sausage meatball pig fatback. Jowl frankfurter landjaeger biltong capicola sausage tri-tip salami sirloin jerky kevin doner. Tri-tip sausage chicken boudin ham.
<br><br>
Does your lorem ipsum text long for something a little meatier? Give our generator a try… it’s tasty!">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
</button>

<br><br>

<button type="button" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
    class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-text-too" title="Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami tri-tip capicola landjaeger. Kielbasa flank turkey ham hock, fatback capicola chuck jerky tail. Drumstick venison bresaola, ham hock brisket flank doner shankle tail spare ribs short ribs bacon turducken. Pancetta kielbasa turkey pork loin, turducken jerky strip steak. Pancetta shank t-bone tail, beef sirloin jowl frankfurter chicken jerky leberkas beef ribs swine hamburger turkey. Turducken ribeye jerky ball tip shank, capicola corned beef meatloaf frankfurter. Pork belly drumstick prosciutto jerky chicken tail pork loin, shoulder landjaeger sirloin sausage pig.
<br><br>
Chuck pork belly ribeye beef ribs. Kielbasa swine beef pancetta, boudin chicken doner beef ribs shankle venison landjaeger corned beef jowl capicola. Pastrami kielbasa flank, pig brisket turducken cow beef ribs porchetta landjaeger turkey. Pork shankle kielbasa corned beef hamburger filet mignon turducken. Strip steak ham hock t-bone tongue prosciutto drumstick. Sirloin jerky rump meatball. Shoulder capicola jerky meatball, sirloin short loin ground round drumstick rump filet mignon shankle.
<br><br>
Tail pork t-bone beef ribs. Kielbasa ham hock pig venison, salami porchetta capicola ball tip shoulder biltong pork chop filet mignon beef ribs. Spare ribs kevin leberkas capicola, shankle pork belly ham strip steak swine. Salami capicola tongue spare ribs, ham venison meatball.
<br><br>
Tri-tip ribeye biltong beef ribs shankle chicken turducken jerky. Pork loin landjaeger capicola salami, rump kielbasa pork chop shank spare ribs kevin jowl. Chicken drumstick bacon leberkas, jowl tri-tip ground round venison andouille short ribs pork loin boudin flank shankle. Short loin shank ribeye swine, bresaola shankle jerky drumstick. Meatloaf shoulder turkey prosciutto corned beef, boudin meatball shankle venison doner pork chop rump biltong pig shank.
<br><br>
T-bone landjaeger porchetta pancetta. Ham hock tail sausage meatball pig fatback. Jowl frankfurter landjaeger biltong capicola sausage tri-tip salami sirloin jerky kevin doner. Tri-tip sausage chicken boudin ham.
<br><br>
Does your lorem ipsum text long for something a little meatier? Give our generator a try… it’s tasty!">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
</button>
```

---

```
$(function(){   
    $('.btn-text-pop').popover({html:true});        
    $('.btn-text-too').tooltip({html:true});
});
```

***Exemplo Online:*** [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8peosk5f/12/)

Comment: Uma parte resolvida mesmo, fiz só uma adaptações ao meu uso, no css eu diminui um pouco o max-width. Mas o que ainda não consegui fazer é que as quebras de linha sejam exibidas com quebras e não corrido da forma que esta.

Comment: Entendi @MarceloDiniz vou ver !!! se conseguir posto aqui.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz veja o esse link http://jsfiddle.net/8peosk5f/12/ e a edição na resposta!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu cheguei a colocar as configurações para html, mas não funcionou. Vi o seu exemplo e esta ok, mas isso pq tem os `<br>` , já no texto de exemplo não tem e é como esta sendo salvo no banco de dados, sem nada (provavelmente ele salva um \n) mas mesmo quando vou olhar direto na base não exibe nem o \n e só uma quebra de linha.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz qual é a linguagem?

Comment: Por traz estou usando php. Se eu colocar um `nl2br` já funciona. Valew

Comment: Sim @MarceloDiniz coloque `nl2br` que ele vai se encarregar de colocar a quebra de linha para você!!! rs

Comment: E @Maria, sem querer abusar, mas saberia me dizer, para quando eu clicar fora do popover ele já fechar!?

Comment: Coloque `data-trigger="focus"` no `<button` igual no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgLyumzL/